# Find the last line in text file and select the first 10 char and print to a new file?

Tags: c++

I need to find the last line of a text file and select the first 10 characters and print that 10 chars to a new text file.

I am able to open a file, read the data and write that to a new file, but I can't find the last line, select 10 characters and print that value to a new file.

Kindly help me.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <iostream.h> 
#include <fstream.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int main() { 
    unsigned int number_of_lines = 0; 
    FILE *infile = fopen("D:\\example.txt", "r"); 
    int ch; 

    while (EOF != (ch=getc(infile)))
        if ('\n' == ch)
            ++number_of_lines; 

    int linescount = number_of_lines+1; 
    cout << linescount << endl;

    system("pause"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please show your current code here.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int number_of_lines = 0;
    FILE *infile = fopen("D:\\example.txt", "r");
    int ch;

    while (EOF != (ch=getc(infile)))
        if ('\n' == ch)
            ++number_of_lines;
        int linescount = number_of_lines+1;
    cout<<linescount<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

Comment: For the future: put your code in the question, not the comments! You can edit your post and paste the code there.

Comment: A naive solution would be to start from the beginning and use getline on every line, passing to a string, until it reaches eof, and then your string will have the last line in the file.  You should probably read the documentation on the function you are using to open the file for reading though, as it may have a member function that places the stream position at the beginning of the last line.

Answer (score 6):

```
ifstream file;
string filename="D:\\example.txt";
file.open(filename.c_str());

string line;
while(getline(file,line));
```

Now you have your last line in the string `line`

now send the 10 chars of `line` to an output file.
`line.substr(0,10)` will fetch the first ten chars.

Comment: it was working dude another thing how to insert these 10 chars to another line after 21 chars (example: another new file is having this line "This is the last ten char:" and my ten chars is this "My value" i need is "This is the last ten chars:My value" the line in the new file is static

Comment: i can able to get the last line data but one problem if the last line is null then i cant fix this error kindly help me...    const char * c = filepath.c_str();
    file.open(c);
    while(file.eof())
    {
     file.getline(temp,1000000);                
    }